# Instance variable in java and c++

Tags: java, c++

as I understood, In java all the variables are refernces.

On the next code:

```
class Parent { 
    public int x = 12; 
} 
class Child extend Parent { 
public int x = 42; 
} 
Parent p = new Parent(); 
System.out.println(p.x); 
12 
Child c = new Child(); 
System.out.println(c.x); 
42 
p = c; // be careful here! 
System.out.println(p.x); 
12
```

I think that there is no Slicing here, because we talk about refernces. For that reason, I don't understand why `"12"` is printed. `p` is now points to the area of `c`, and `c.x` is 42.

The same is happening in the next code on C++:

```
class Parent { 
  public:
    void example () { cout << "Parent" << endl; } 
}; 
class Child : public Parent { 
  public: 
    void example () { cout << "Child" << endl; } 
};

Parent * p = new Parent(); 
p->example() 
Parent 

Child * c = new Child(); 
c->example() 
Child 

p = c; // be careful here! 
p->example() 
Parent
```

Answer (score 7):

You are hiding members, not overriding. For the Java example, you cannot override a field. You need to use a function. For the C++ example, your function in `Parent` must be virtual to be overridden by `Child`. Otherwise you simply hide the function.

C++:

```
class Parent { 
  public:
    virtual void example () { cout << "Parent" << endl; } 
}; 
class Child : public Parent { 
  public: 
    void example () { cout << "Child" << endl; } 
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm thinking C#... :)

Answer (score 4):

In Java, you cannot override a field, you can only hide it.  Child has two fields `Parent.x` and `Child.x`.  The reference type determines which field you means by `.x`

Answer (score 1):

for the java side you are declaring 2 separate variables

meaning that for a `Child c` there's `c.x` and a `((Parent)c).x` that are different variables with their own values

Answer (score 0):

That's because you user p.x, not c.x. The field x is not overriden by Child (as, for example, a method getX() would be). Instead, it is in the subobject, corresponding to a Child class. So, you actually have 2 x: Parent.x and Child.x.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can only hide the field and not override it.
`For Java`

`p=c`

Now p has the reference  of c thus you get answer **=12**